# \section*{} leaves space even at the beginning of the page in memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir

In my document in memoir class, there is a chapter with unnumbered sections --- \section*{}. (The effect is the same if the sections are numbered but \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} is used.)

When a new section begins at the top of a page, it leaves vertical space as if the section number were printed there.

I find it odd and would have expected Latex to start at the top of the page in such a case.

Is this an intended behavior --- as in 'Best Typesetting Practice'?

If not, how do I suppress it?

Comment: What's `\section*{}` for? If you want to “leave some blank space” just use `\bigskip` or a similar command.

Comment: @egreg, point well taken. Will use \bigskip instead.
Also, if you give it as an answer, will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\section*{}` just to get some blank vertical space is not the best way to accomplish the task; a vertical space is obtained by commands such as

```
\smallskip
\medskip
\bigskip
```

In the standard classes `\smallskip` is 3pt shrinkable to 2pt and (optimally)  stretchable to 4pt; `\medskip` is 6pt shrinkable to 4pt and (optimally) stretchable to 8pt; `\bigskip` is 12pt shrinkable to 8pt and (optimally) stretchable to 16pt.

You're free to use also `\vspace` that takes a rubber length specification:

```
\vspace{24pt plus 8pt minus 8pt}
```

would be the double of `\bigskip`.

Remember that under normal conditions these commands should be issued between paragraphs:

```
... end of a paragraph.

\medskip % leave some vertical space

Start of a paragraph ...
```

Don't be too generous with vertical spacing: `\medskip` is usually sufficient.

Comment: Read the manual. \fancybreak{} (bank line before and after), leaves a blank line in the about and the text after is **not** indented (meant as a note to the OP, not egreg)